# My GPS reminder keeps asking me for enable GPS

Tags: java, android, google-maps, gps

I have provide a GPS reminder in my app, but when i enable my gps and return to my mainactivty, my gps reminder ask me again, again and a agin when i press the googlemaps button. It only works when I close the program and restart the app

This is my MainActivityClass.

```
GPSTracker gps;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    gps = new GPSTracker(MainActivity.this);
}
```

My button to googlemaps.

```
public void googlemaps(View view) {
    if (gps.canGetLocation()) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, GoogleMaps.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    } else {
        gps.showSettingsAlert();
    }
}
```

this is my GPS tracker class

```
public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

private final Context mContext;

// flag for GPS status
boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

// flag for GPS status
boolean canGetLocation = false;

Location location; // location

public LocationManager locationManager;

public GPSTracker(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;
    getLocation();
}

public Location getLocation() {
    try {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) this
                .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // getting GPS status
        isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        if (!isGPSEnabled) {
        } else {
            this.canGetLocation = true;

            // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
            if (isGPSEnabled) {
                if (location == null) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 10, 2000, this);

                    Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return location;
}


/**
 * Function to show settings alert dialog On pressing Settings button will
 * lauch Settings Options
 * */
public void showSettingsAlert() {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog
            .setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

    // On pressing Settings button
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(
                            Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                    mContext.startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

    // on pressing cancel button
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

    // Showing Alert Message
    alertDialog.show();
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to retest if the GPS has been enabled after you show your dialog.  From the looks of it, you set your `canGetLocation` variable once when you create the class (via a call to `getLocation()`.  Adding a call to 'getLocation()`in`onResume()` should solve your problem. I would recommend breaking the logic to see if the GPS is enabled into its own method.